# Alternatives to Qt Signals and Slots for Inter-Object Communication

Tags: c++, qt

What are alternatives to using Qt-like signals and slots for communication between two objects (class instances) in both directions?

I know this can be realized by saving a reference of the other in each object. However, this gets sort of confusing when there are many different objects and all objects are supposed to interact with (and thus to know) one another.

The other question I've had was how Qt signals and slots implement this inter-object communication internally (a simple overview of the internal course of events would be helpful)?

A Qt example of what I'm talking about would be the following. Both objects, c and d, can emit a signal that is connected to a slot of the other.

```
class Chicken : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Chicken() = default;

public slots:
    void helloBackDuck() {
        std::cout << "Hello Back Duck" << std::endl;
    }
    
signals:
    void helloDuck();

};

class Duck : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Duck() = default;

public slots:
    void helloBackChicken() {
        std::cout << "Hello Back Chicken" << std::endl;
    }
    
signals:
    void helloChicken();
};

int main() {
    Chicken c;
    Duck d;
    
    connect(&c, &Chicken::helloDuck, &d, &Duck::helloBackChicken);
    connect(&d, &Duck::helloChicken, &c, &Chicken::helloBackDuck);
}
```

Comment: Qt internals can best be looked up in the Qt source code, but from *very* high up, each QObject has a list of objects that it is connected to, and emitting a signal means iterating through that list, checking for the signal each connection is for, and then calling a member function.

Comment: What kind of "alternative" are you looking for? Signals and slots work in-process. You want an out-of-process alternative? If not: are you sure to use Qt? Because GTK or Copperspice or wx give you vaguely similar things too. As does writing explicit pointer-wrangling code (which you call "sort of confusing"). Please clarify what direction you're asking for (and maybe say why Qt signal/slot doesn't do it for you).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  What's wrong with using `Qt` signals/slots?  What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks @AdriaandeGroot , that gives me a better understanding for what "magic" is happening inside Qt.

I don't have a problem with Qt signals and slots at all. This is more a programming theory kind of question. I'm asking myself if there is some whole other approach I hadn't yet found. What exactly do you mean by out-of-process? Thanks you guys!

Comment: function pointers, but i wasn't successful when i tried.

Comment: How Qt works: https://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work.html and references therein

Comment: To put it in other words: In a big software project. Are there common alternatives to the signals-and-slots design paradigm (not only C++)? Or are signals and slots used pretty much everywhere?

Comment: I personally don't like signal-slot in Qt, because I don't like lots of `connect()` lines.
Maybe actor-framework can be an alternative? It uses asynchronous message passing. I dont' have any experience with it. https://www.actor-framework.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt Signal and slot mechanism is best choose in Qt programs, but if you want to know about other options, you have these:

1. You can develop your own Observer structure that would be like Qt signal and slot but you should invent the wheel from the beginning by yourself.

   You should create an Observe class and a Subject class. In the beginning connect your Observer by passing a reference of it to Subject and as soon as the condition meet Subject will call the update function of all of the instances (emit).

   For more explanation check this [link](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer/cpp/example).
2. Another option is using Boost signal2 that is also similar to Qt signal slot but from third party libraries. Usage is similar to Qt signal.

   For more explanation check [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html).